# RxAndroid, Retrofit 2 unit test Schedulers.io

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I am newly learned the RxAndroid but unfortunately the book I studied did not covered any unit test. I have searched a lot on google but failed to find any simple tutorial that cover the RxAndroid unit test in precise way.

I have basically wrote a small REST API using RxAndroid and Retrofit 2. Here is the ApiManager class:

```
public class MyAPIManager {
    private final MyService myService;

    public MyAPIManager() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder b = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        b.readTimeout(35000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        b.connectTimeout(35000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        b.addInterceptor(logging);
        OkHttpClient client = b.build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.7:8000")
                .client(client)
                .build();

        myService = retrofit.create(MyService.class);
    }

    public Observable<Token> getToken(String username, String password) {
        return myService.getToken(username, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a unit test for `getToken`. Here is my sample test:

```
public class MyAPIManagerTest {
    private MyAPIManager myAPIManager;
    @Test
    public void getToken() throws Exception {
        myAPIManager = new MyAPIManager();

        Observable<Token> o = myAPIManager.getToken("hello", "mytoken");
        o.test().assertSubscribed();
        o.test().assertValueCount(1);
    }

}
```

Due to `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)` the above test does not run on main thread due to which it returns 0 value. If I remove `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)` from `MyAPIManager` then it run well and return 1 value. Is there any way to test with `Schedulers.io`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question and certainly one topic that is lacking a lot of coverage in the community. I would like to share a couple of solutions I personally used and were splendid. These are thought for RxJava 2 but they're available with RxJava 1 just under different names. You will for sure find it if you need it.

1. **RxPlugins and RxAndroidPlugins** (this is my favourite so far)

So Rx actually provides a mechanism to change the schedulers provided by the static methods inside `Schedulers` and `AndroidSchedulers`. These are for example:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler
RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler
RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler
RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler
```

What these do is very simple. They make sure that when you call i.e. `Schedulers.io()` the returned scheduler is the one you provide in the handler set in `setIoSchedulerHandler`. Which scheduler do you want to use? Well you want `Schedulers.trampoline()`. This means that the code will run on the same thread as it was before. If all schedulers are in the trampoline scheduler, then all will be running on the `JUnit` thread. After the tests are run, you can just clean the whole thing by calling:

```
RxJavaPlugins.reset()
RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
```

I think the best approach to this is to use a JUnit rule. Here's a possible one (sorry for the kotlin syntax):

```
class TrampolineSchedulerRule : TestRule {
  private val scheduler by lazy { Schedulers.trampoline() }

  override fun apply(base: Statement?, description: Description?): Statement =
        object : Statement() {
            override fun evaluate() {
                try {
                    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
                    RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
                    RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
                    RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
                    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
                    base?.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

At the top of your unit test you just need to declare a public attribute annotated with `@Rule` and instantiated with this class:

```
@Rule
public TrampolineSchedulerRule rule = new TrampolineSchedulerRule()
```

in kotlin

```
@get:Rule
val rule = TrampolineSchedulerRule()
```

2. **Injecting schedulers (a.k.a. dependency injection)**

Another possibility is to inject the schedulers in your classes so at test time you can inject again the `Schedulers.trampoline()` and in your app you can inject the normal schedulers. This might work for a while, but it will soon become cumbersome when you need to inject loads of schedulers just for a simple class. Here's one way of doing this

```
public class MyAPIManager {
  private final MyService myService;
  private final Scheduler io;
  private final Scheduler mainThread;

  public MyAPIManager(Scheduler io, Scheduler mainThread) {
    // initialise everything
    this.io = io;
    this.mainThread = mainThread;
  }

  public Observable<Token> getToken(String username, String password) {
    return myService.getToken(username, password)
            .subscribeOn(io);
            .observeOn(mainThread);
  }
}
```

As you can see we can now tell the class the actual schedulers. In your tests you'd do something like:

```
public class MyAPIManagerTest {
  private MyAPIManager myAPIManager;
  @Test
  public void getToken() throws Exception {
    myAPIManager = new MyAPIManager(
          Schedulers.trampoline(),
          Schedulers.trampoline());

    Observable<Token> o = myAPIManager.getToken("hello", "mytoken");
    o.test().assertSubscribed();
    o.test().assertValueCount(1);
  }
}
```

The key points are:

- You want it on the `Schedulers.trampoline()` scheduler to make sure everything's run on the JUnit thread
- You need to be able to modify the schedulers while testing.

That's all. Hope it helps.

=========================================================

Here is Java version which I have used after following above Kotlin example:

```
public class TrampolineSchedulerRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new MyStatement(base);
    }

    public class MyStatement extends Statement {
        private final Statement base;

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            try {
                RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                base.evaluate();
            } finally {
                RxJavaPlugins.reset();
                RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
            }
        }

        public MyStatement(Statement base) {
            this.base = base;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have followed the Kotlin example for simplicity after converting to Java and it works well.

Comment: There is a third way. In a test, instead of subscribing you can call `Observable.blockingFirst()` or `Observable.blockingIterable()`. This way the test thread waits for the observable to complete and when it does you can validate the results. Its not as clean as using `Schedulers.trampoline()`, but it requires less setup.